# Vanishing of a quadratic form along the orbits of a unitary group

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a (complex) Hilbert space and let $B\colon H\times H\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous sesquilinear form (i.e. a continuous function that is linear in one argument and conjugate-linear in the other). Consider the associated quadratic form $Q(\psi)=B(\psi, \psi)$.

Assume that there exists a continuous one-parameter group of unitary operators $\{e^{i\theta T}\}_{\theta\in \mathbb{R}}$ such that 
$$\begin{array}{cc}
Q\left( e^{i\theta T}\psi - \psi \right)=O\left(\lvert \theta\rvert^3\right), & \theta \to 0.
\end{array}
$$
Here $\psi$ belongs to the domain of the self-adjoint generator $T$ and is fixed.

> **Question**. Is it true that $Q(T\psi)=0$?

Intuitively, this should be true because for very small values of $\theta$ one has $e^{i\theta T}\psi-\psi\approx i\theta T\psi$. Since $Q$ is continuous, one expects that $Q(i\theta T\psi)=O(\lvert \theta\rvert^3)$, which can only happen if $Q$ vanishes along the whole (complex) line generated by $T\psi$.

A special case of this result is used implicitly in a paper which I am reading (reference below). The point of this question is understanding whether the result continues to hold in this more abstract setting.

---

T. Duyckaerts, F. Merle, S. Roudenko. "Maximizers for the Strichartz norm for small solutions of mass-critical NLS", Annali della Scuola Normale Superiore di Pisa, Vol. X, issue 2 (2011).

[link](http://annaliscienze.sns.it/index.php?page=Article&id=216) -  [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.0297)

The relevant result is used implicitly at the beginning of section 3. Warning: notation there is a bit different. The function $\psi$ of this question corresponds to $G_0$ of the paper.

Comment: dunno, and having a little trouble picturing. What are the hypotheses and question when $H$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: @WillJagy: If $H=\mathbb{C}^n$, then $Q(\phi)=\langle A\phi, \phi\rangle$ for a symmetric matrix $A$ and $G$ is a self-adjoint matrix, that generates the dynamical system $\dot{x}=iGx$. We fix $\phi \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and we consider the trajectory $e^{i\theta G}\phi$. By assumption, the translated quadratic form $Q(e^{i\theta G}\phi - \phi)$ vanishes along the whole trajectory. Then the question is whether $Q(iG\phi)$ vanishes. Not really a simplification, except that now one should not worry about the domain of $G$.

Comment: Thank you...in this case, is $G$ real? I was trying to think how you wind up with unitary matrix. Also, sometimes there are arguments where finite dimensional somethings are dense in bounded or continuous other things...

Comment: @WillJagy: Yes, $G$ can be thought of as being real, since it is self-adjoint. To be honest, I don't think that those "real or complex" details matter much, here. Also the unitarity of the dynamical system is not very important, I guess. I even think that the following, more general result is true: "if $Q(\gamma(t; \phi)-\phi)\equiv 0$ for a curve $\gamma(t; \phi)$ that starts at $\phi$, then $Q(\dot{\gamma}(0; \phi))=0$". (Maybe my question would have been clearer if I had stated it this way from the beginning?)

Comment: I don't know, and i'm hardly one to ask about general Hilbert spaces. i just thought finite dimension typically gives a problem that can be solved, possibly by ugly arguments, especially by using derivatives and matrix calculations that may not be legitimate in infinite dimension. Of course, such a result need not generalize...

Comment: I edited the question a little. I have let $\phi$ be fixed once and for all. Hopefully it's a bit clearer now. (BTW, thanx for your interest)

Comment: I see your answer (although deleted), good.

Comment: @WillJagy: There is an error, that derivative is wrong. Of course the derivative of a quadratic form vanishes at the origin, so the only identity one can get by differentiating along the trajectory is $0=0$. I am thinking at another approach now. Still doesn't work, but I think there is a progress! (BTW you are right that thinking "finite dimensional" is very useful).

Comment: Alright, that explains why you deleted it. Well, keep at it, I'm sure you will get it eventually.

Comment: @WillJagy: I finally got it, now it looks fine to me. It was extremely easy! The hard part was posing the question correctly. Note that I have relaxed the assumptions a little to better match the linked paper, in which $Q$ is the second order term of a Taylor expansion. This is why there is a $O(\lvert \theta\rvert^3)$ there.

Comment: Giuseppe, good work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is rather easy. Using the homogeneity of $Q$ we may write
$$
Q(e^{i\theta T}\psi -\psi)=\lvert \theta\rvert^2 Q\left( \frac{e^{i\theta T}\psi -\psi}{\theta}\right),$$
and the left hand side is $O(\lvert \theta\rvert^3)$ by assumption, so 
$$
Q\left( \frac{e^{i\theta T}\psi -\psi}{\theta} \right) = O(\theta).$$
Since $Q$ is continuous, taking the limit as $\theta \to 0$ we obtain
$$Q(iT\psi)=0, $$
as desired.